# Перебор вариантов паролей из списка

Tags: python, json

Только начинаю изучать Python.

Есть код

```
import requests
import json

password = [
'123456',
'123456789',
'qwerty',
'12345678',
'111111',
'1234567890',
'1234567',
'password',
'123123',
'987654321',
'qwertyuiop',
'mynoob',
'123321',
'666666',
'18atcskd2w',
'7777777',
'1q2w3e4r',
'654321',
'555555',
'3rjs1la7qe',
'google',
'1q2w3e4r5t',
'123qwe',
'zxcvbnm',
'1q2w3e' ]

while i in password:
print (i)

response = requests.post('https://playground.learnqa.ru/ajax/api/get_secret_password_homework', data={'login':'super_admin','password':password})
got_cookie = dict(response.cookies)

our_cookie = (got_cookie['auth_cookie'])
print(our_cookie)

response_check_auth = requests.post('https://playground.learnqa.ru/ajax/api/check_auth_cookie', headers={'auth_cookie':our_cookie})
print(response_check_auth.text)
```

Есть задание - нужно в переменную password, которая находится в заголовках запроса response поочередно пробрасывать все варианты паролей из списка переменной password. На один из этих паролей (предполагаю, что где-то в середине) - должен будет прийти успешный ответ, и в этот момент нужно будет остановиться.

Дайте направление, подскажите с решением

Comment: "Перебор из списка" - это фактически всегда цикл for, не понятно зачем вам вдруг while понадобился.

Comment: Первым делом в этом коде появится `IdentationError`.

Answer (score 2):

Можешь перебирать список через for и выходить из него, когда находишь. У меня ни один из этих паролей не подошёл, использовал данные из твоего вопроса

```
import requests

passwords = [
    "123456",
    "123456789",
    "qwerty",
    "12345678",
    "111111",
    "1234567890",
    "1234567",
    "password",
    "123123",
    "987654321",
    "qwertyuiop",
    "mynoob",
    "123321",
    "666666",
    "18atcskd2w",
    "7777777",
    "1q2w3e4r",
    "654321",
    "555555",
    "3rjs1la7qe",
    "google",
    "1q2w3e4r5t",
    "123qwe",
    "zxcvbnm",
    "1q2w3e"
]

result = "<Unknown>"
for password in passwords:
    print(f"Trying \"{password}\"")
    response = requests.post("https://playground.learnqa.ru/ajax/api/get_secret_password_homework", data={"login": "super_admin", "password": password})
    got_cookie = dict(response.cookies)
    our_cookie = (got_cookie["auth_cookie"])

    response_check_auth = requests.post('https://playground.learnqa.ru/ajax/api/check_auth_cookie', headers={"auth_cookie": our_cookie})
    if response_check_auth.text != "You are NOT authorized":
        result = password
        break

print(f"Password is: {result}")
```